# DynamoDB using the Serverless Python Template gives KeyError for body

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

The code for the lambda function is the following:

```
import json
import logging
import os
import time
import uuid

import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def create(event, context):
    data = json.loads(event['body'])
    if 'text' not in data:
        logging.error("Validation Failed")
        raise Exception("Couldn't create the todo item.")
    
    timestamp = str(time.time())

    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE'])

    item = {
        'id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
        'name': data['text'],
        'description': data['text'],
        'price': data['text'],
        
        'createdAt': timestamp,
        'updatedAt': timestamp,
    }

    # write the todo to the database
    table.put_item(Item=item)

    # create a response
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(item)
    }

    return response
```

The test using AWS' Lambda's testing feature is:

```
{
  "name": "Masks",
  "description": "A box of 50 disposable masks",
  "price": "$10"
}
```

The log output is:

```
START RequestId: 5cf1c00a-dba5-4ef6-b5e7-b692d8235ffe Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'body'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/todos/create.py", line 12, in create
    data = json.loads(event['body'])END RequestId: 5cf1c00a-dba5-4ef6-b5e7-b692d8235ffe
```

Why is "body" giving me a key error? How do I fix this? The template is directly from [www.severless.com](http://www.severless.com), and based off of online tutorials, people have used the exact same code, albie with different values, successfully?

I've tried changing variable names and value to no avail.

```
sls deploy
```

Does successfully create the table, but I am unable to input any data into it.
Edit 1: For those of you unfamiliar with AWS' Lambda Test feature, using Postman to input the same data is leading either to a 502 Gateway Error.

Comment: What do you meany by "test using AWS CloudWatch"?

Comment: AWS Cloudwatch lets you test Lambda functions with a test case. Please check the updated question.

Comment: If what you provided is your test `event`, then it clearly does not have any `body`. Yet you are trying to access it in `event['body']`. Same it does not have any `text`, but you try to access it `data['text']`. Thus its not clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create an entry in my DynamoDB table for Item.

Comment: Based on what? Are you confident that this is your correct event: `{
  "name": "Masks",
  "description": "A box of 50 disposable masks",
  "price": "$10"
}`.  Because it does not match your code at all.

Comment: So it has 6 attributes, id which is supposed to be automatically generates and the primary key, name, description and price as three strings, and a timestap for creation and updates. I want to make an entry to my table. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: I added the answer. You can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is the correct `event` object:

```
{
  "name": "Masks",
  "description": "A box of 50 disposable masks",
  "price": "$10"
}
```

your code which matches this event should be:

```
import json
import logging
import os
import time
import uuid

import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def create(event, context):
   
    timestamp = str(time.time())

    table = dynamodb.Table(os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE'])

    item = {
        'id': str(uuid.uuid1()),
        'name': event['name'],
        'description': event['description'],
        'price': event['price'],        
        'createdAt': timestamp,
        'updatedAt': timestamp,
    }

    # write the todo to the database
    table.put_item(Item=item)

    # create a response
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(item)
    }

    return response
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. How would I trigger this function and pass the three strings from a Flutter application using a form? I cannot find relevant documentation for it anywhere.